# SAT Geometric Visualization

Tags: geometry

[image]

I can't choose between A and C. Can u draw a picture to disprove A?

Comment: Maybe look from above, easier on the neck.

Comment: hint : dashed square and the outer square must align in same orientation

Comment: @GaneshTadi  right, when the line segments are drawn to connect the midpoints the line segments are parallel to the edges of the base.  Is this why the answer is C?

Comment: exactly ! thats how i have also interpreted the question :)

Comment: if it helps, think of cross section with a plane parallel to the base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your points lie on the midpoints of the sloped edges of the pyramid in a way that looks something like this.

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image: sketch]$\tag{Face-on View}$

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image: points]$\tag{Arial View}$

So the four lines over the pyramid's faces should connect these red points.
Figures $C$ & $D$ satisfy this condition though only $C$ goes over the triangular faces ($D$ would go over the edges, not the faces).

The reason it isn't $A$ is that the points in $A$ wouldn't lie on the edges. In fact, they would lie in the middle of each face.

Comment: As an aside, does anyone know of a simple way to centre images? I figured out a way but I'd like to know if there's a command. Thanks.